# AIX lspath doesn't show any output

Tags: unix, aix

```
root@xxxxx:/>lspath
root@xxxxx:/>lspath -l hdisk20
lspath: 0514-538 Cannot perform the requested function because the
        specified device does not support multiple paths.
root@xxxxx:/>lsvg -p rootvg
rootvg:
PV_NAME           PV STATE          TOTAL PPs   FREE PPs    FREE DISTRIBUTION
hdisk20           active            799         664         159..125..60..160..160
root@xxxxx:/>lsdev -Cc disk |grep hdisk20
hdisk20 Available 02-T1-01 Hitachi Disk Array (Fibre)
root@xxxxx:/>lslpp -L |grep -i hitachi
  Hitachi.aix.support.rte   5.0.52.3    C     F    AIX Support for Hitachi Disk
root@xxxxx:/>lslpp -L |grep -i mpio
  devices.common.IBM.mpio.rte
                            5.3.12.1    C     F    MPIO Disk Path Control Module
root@xxxxx:/>oslevel -s
5300-12-01-1016

hdisk20 Available 02-T1-01 Hitachi Disk Array (Fibre)
---------------
hdisk20 U8233.E8B.106178P-V10-C102-T1-W50060E8016050814-L0 Hitachi Disk Array (Fibre)

Manufacturer................HITACHI
Machine Type and Model......OPEN-V
Part Number.................v..l
ROS Level and ID............37303036
Serial Number...............50 10508
EC Level....................
FRU Number..................
Device Specific.(Z0)........00000332EF000002
Device Specific.(Z1)........01CF 2E ....
Device Specific.(Z2).........
Device Specific.(Z3).........
Device Specific.(Z4).........l
Device Specific.(Z5).........P
Device Specific.(Z6)........
```

these are SAN disk and have vio setup with npiv

I think lspath comes bundled with bos.rte, is there a way to reinstall it, just to check, even I think that should not be the case.

I have following bundles installed:

- devices.common.IBM.mpio.rte
- 5.3.12.1 COMMITTED MPIO Disk Path Control Module
- Hitachi.aix.support.rte 5.0.52.3 COMMITTED AIX Support for Hitachi Dis